# PHP generated pass is not being installed in wallet on an iPhone

Tags: php, ios, laravel-5.1, passbook, coupon

I am using this [passgenerator](https://github.com/thenextweb/passgenerator) library to generate a `.pkpass` which is supposed to be installed on an apple wallet on iPhone. The `.pkpass` file is generated successfully but it could not be added to "wallet" on iPhone it even don't show any error when I try to open this file from an email attachment. 
When I open it with "Pass Viewer" on mac it shows some error on bar-code area. Here is screenshot;

[image: coupon]

I don't know where I am doing something wrong. I am using laravel 5.1 and I have required this package correctly and also as documentation asked to set environment variables to set certificates paths.

```
CERTIFICATE_PATH= './assets/certificates/PassCertificate.p12'
CERTIFICATE_PASS= "mypassword"
WWDR_CERTIFICATE='./assets/certificates/WWDRCA.pem'
```

Here is my controller code where I am setting its configurations in json format.

```
public function index(PassGenerator $pass)
    {
        $pass_identifier = 'testPkPass';  // This, if set, it would allow for retrieval later on of the created Pass
        $pkpass = $pass->getPass($pass_identifier);
        if (!$pkpass) {
            $pkpass = $this->createWalletPass($pass_identifier);
        }
        $path = storage_path().'/app/passgenerator/'.$pass_identifier.'.pkpass';
        return Response::download($path, $pass_identifier.'.pkpass', [
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'binary',
            'Content-Description' => 'File Transfer',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="myTestingPass.pkpass"',
            'Content-length' => strlen($pkpass),
            'Content-Type' => PassGenerator::getPassMimeType(),
            'Pragma' => 'no-cache',
        ]);
    }

    private function createWalletPass($pass_identifier)
    {

        $pass = new PassGenerator($pass_identifier);

        $pass_definition = [
            "description"       => "description",
            "formatVersion"     => 1,
            "organizationName"  => "Black Book",
            "passTypeIdentifier"=> "pass.biz.myIdentifier.coupon",
            "serialNumber"      => "123456",
            "teamIdentifier"    => "xyz",
            "foregroundColor"   => "rgb(255, 255, 255)",
            "backgroundColor"   => "rgb(44, 49, 51)",
            "barcode" => [
                "message"   => "encodedmessageonQR",
                "format"    => "PKBarcodeFormatQR",
                "altText"   => "altextfortheQR",
                "messageEncoding"=> "utf-8",
            ],
            "coupon" => [
                "headerFields" => [
                    [
                        "key" => "header",
                        "label" => "Value",
                        "value" => "30%"
                    ]
                ],
                "secondaryFields" => [
                    [
                        "key" => "welcome",
                        "label" => "",
                        "value" => "Welcome valued customer!"
                    ],
                    [
                        "key" => "date",
                        "label" => "EXPIRES",
                        "value" => "2016/06/29"
                    ]
                ],
                "backFields" => [
                    [
                        "key" => "terms",
                        "label" => "Terms & Conditions",
                        "value" => "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
                    ], [
                        "key" => "contact",
                        "label" => "Contact Us",
                        "value" => "[Contact-us] Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco."
                    ], 
                ],
            ],
        ];

        $pass->setPassDefinition($pass_definition);

        // Add assets to the PKPass package
        $pass->addAsset(base_path('public/assets/wallet/background.png'));
        $pass->addAsset(base_path('public/assets/wallet/thumbnail.png'));
        $pass->addAsset(base_path('public/assets/wallet/icon.png'));
        $pass->addAsset(base_path('public/assets/wallet/logo.png'));

        $pkpass = $pass->create();
        return $pkpass;
    }
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong with configuration or somewhere else.

Comment: What do your Xcode logs say? If you don't have a Mac or Xcode, can you post a link to the .pkapss bundle.  You don't have an expiry date set in your JSON so I suspect that the barcode is greyed because your Pass Type ID certificate has expired or has been revoked.

Comment: Also you have an empty string in your secondary label.  Remove that key or add a space.  A null string will cause an error.

Comment: @PassKit I have changed my secondary field but it does not have any affect. Can you provide me your email address so I can send you an email of pass package.

Comment: Sorry no, this is a community site - answers should benefit everyone, not just individuals.  Please check your certificate first.

Comment: Ops sorry @PassKit. here is the link to dropbox [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vsl8pr887ku204s/123testPkPass.pkpass?dl=0)

Comment: I have valid certificates downloaded from apple developer account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a problem with your signature.

```
Aug  5 16:38:36 pfr MobileSafari(PassKitCore)[2017] <Notice>: Error evaluating trust: <private>
Aug  5 16:38:36 pfr MobileSafari(PassKitCore)[2017] <Notice>: Signature validation: *** FAILED ***
Aug  5 16:38:36 pfr MobileSafari(PassKitCore)[2017] <Fault>: Invalid data error reading pass <private>. <private>
Aug  5 16:38:36 pfr MobileSafari(PassKitCore)[2017] <Notice>: Invalid data error reading pass <private>. <private>
Aug  5 16:38:36 pfr MobileSafari[2017] <Notice>: PassBook Pass download failed: The pass cannot be read because it isn't valid.
```

You `pass.json` has a team identifier `"teamIdentifier":"5w2h"`

According to your signature file, your team identifier is WY92JHSJ83.  Fix your team identifier and try again.

Also you can drop your `background.png` and `thumbnail.png` as they are not valid images for a coupon format pass.

Comment: Thank you @PassKit. You are life saver. Can please tell me how can I check these logs as you did for debugging.

Comment: You need an iPhone, a Mac and Xcode.  Hook your iPhone up to the Mac, then in Xcode select Window->Devices then select your device.  The logs are output in in the bottom pane.